# Exclude relationship data in laravel attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have 2 table on my laravel app, and they are related.

Table 1:

```
class User extends Model {
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
  
  public function post() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
  }
}
```

Table 2:

```
class Post extends Model {
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'info', 'image'];

  pretected $appends = ['post_by'];
      
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function getPostByAttribute() {
    return $this->user->name;
  }
}
```

Now, when i fetch the post table it return with user object which is the related user to the post.

This is the result look like:

```
data: {
  title: "Test",
  info: "Test Info",
  image: null,
  post_by: "Test User", // this is only i want
  user: {name: "Test User", email: "user@test.com"} // this is i want to exclude
}
```

If the question already exist, please give me reference to it.

Comment: Would you please attach how you fetch the data?

Comment: @ShakilAhmmed this is how i fetch the post data: return Post::where('title', $title)->first();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query method instead of the relationship method to get the value:

```
public function getPostByAttribute() {
    return $this->user()->first()->name;
}
```

Comment: At the first try i thought that this did not work, but it actually work after i clear my routes, thanks man :)